# Как Angular 1 узнает, что в $scope произошли изменения?

Tags: angularjs

Допустим есть функция по нажатию на которой в $scope что-то изменяется, например:

```
$scope.update = function(newName) {
    $scope.name = newName;
}

<button ng-click=update('blabla')>Test</button>
```

Как ангуляр узнает были ли изменения в $scope и запускает digest?
$scope это же обычный объект, это же не функция типа:

```
 fn(newName) {
     $scope.name = newName;
     $digest(); // обход watcher-ов... как он добавляет эту функцию? точно не знаю как она называется...
 }
```

Или ангуляр после нажатия на ng-click автоматом запускает функцию которая обходит все watchers, даже если изменения в $scope не было?

Comment: _ангуляр после нажатия на ng-click автоматом запускает функцию которая обходит все watchers, даже если изменения в $scope не было_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если посмотреть в исходниках [определении директивы `ng-click`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/07849779ba365f371a8caa3b58e23f677cfdc5ad/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L50) можно увидеть, что в обработчике нативного события вызываются либо [`scope.$evalAsync`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1017), либо [`scope.$apply`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1080)

Обе эти функции запускают digest цикл, в котором и производится проверка изменилось ли что-нибудь и нужно ли обновить view.